# What bibliography style is used here? Including reference page numbers and mathscinet links?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, amsmath, citing

I stumbled upon the following bibliography, which I quite like.

[image: example bibliography]

In particular I appreciate the links to mathscinet (the red MR... numbers, which are actual clickable links) and the page numbers, where the paper is cited in the document (which are also clickable links).

Has anyone seen this bibliography style before? Is this some sort of special math-bibliography package? If not, how can I achieve something similar with the page numbers?

Comment: I don't know of a style exactly like that, but with `biblatex` it should be easy to get linked MR numbers as well as linked backrefs.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the editorial office of the publication from which you culled the screenshot? I'd venture to guess you'll get a much more informative and precise answer.

Comment: maybe check if it's PCMI format. (speculation based on  https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/pcmi-lecture-notes-on-random-matrix-theory/ )

Comment: what publication did this appear in?  if it was published by the ams, chances are it was reprocessed using the `amsrefs` information from mathscinet, with backrefs added.

Comment: Any news here? Can you shed a bit more light on this? Would you be OK with a `biblatex` answer that shows how to get mathreview numbers and backrefs (but not necessarily the *exact* same output for the rest)? Or do you need a `natbib`/BIbTeX/...-compatible solution?

Answer (score 2):

This bibliography looks like it has been produced with `amsrefs`. Both features mentioned in the question can also be achieved with `biblatex`. For page references use the option `backref`. Mathscinet links require some more work, I have packaged it here: https://github.com/pzorin/biblatex-mr (probably not the cleanest solution)

Answer (score 1):

To create the MR link, use `msc-link` option in `amsrefs` package, and be sure to supply the MR number in your bibliography entry. Also note that this requires the `hyperref` package.
I find the easiest way to create the MR link is copy the entire bibtex entry from MathSciNet and use `amsrefs` as I mentioned.
The [`amsrefs` package user guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf) has some other helpful tips.

Working example (using the reference given in MathSciNet's help page):

document.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[msc-links]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
In \cite{MR3385638} the authors proves some phenomenal theorems.


\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```

refs.bib

```
@article {MR3385638,
   AUTHOR = {Saxton, David and Thomason, Andrew},
   TITLE = {Hypergraph containers},
   JOURNAL = {Invent. Math.},
   FJOURNAL = {Inventiones Mathematicae},
   VOLUME = {201},
   YEAR = {2015},
   NUMBER = {3},
   PAGES = {925--992},
   ISSN = {0020-9910},
   MRCLASS = {05C65 (05C69)},
   MRNUMBER = {3385638},
   MRREVIEWER = {Eoin Long},
   DOI = {10.1007/s00222-014-0562-8},
   URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-014-0562-8},
}
```

Prdocues:
[image: MR number is a link]